# Merge a specific table column from one database to another

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two SQL databases. One is an older backup of the other.

I would like to merge only 1 specific table from [user_database0] into [user_database1] using either ssh or inside phpMyAdmin.

That table that I want to restore from backup is called [prefix_table].

However, I don't want to restore all columns from that table [prefix_table], just the [comment] column.

---

One of my biggest concerns is that some of the  rows from the [prefix_table] have been deleted and I DO NOT want to restore those deleted rows from the old database.

**Here is an Example:**

*- Merge table [prefix_table]from **[user_database0]**:

```
                      prefix_table                  
+---------------------------------------------------+
|     id     | name  | comment    | age | person_id |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 1111       | name1 | old text 1 | 01  | 001       |
+------------+-------+------------+-----+-----------+
| 2222       | name2 | old text 2 | 02  | 002       |
+------------+-------+------------+-----+-----------+
| 3333       | name3 | old text 3 | 03  | 003       |
+------------+-------+------------+-----+-----------+
| 4444       | name4 | old text 4 | 04  | 004       |
+------------+-------+------------+-----+-----------+
```

*-Into table [prefix_table] in **[user_database1]** :

```
                       prefix_table                   
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|     id     | name    | comment    | age | person_id |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 1111       | namenew | new text 1 | 99  | 001       |
+------------+---------+------------+-----+-----------+
| 4444       | name4   | new text 4 | 04  | 004       |
+------------+---------+------------+-----+-----------+
| 5555       | name5   | text 1     | 05  | 005       |
+------------+---------+------------+-----+-----------+
| 6666       | name6   | text 2     | 06  | 006       |
+------------+---------+------------+-----+-----------+
```

*- **Resulting** database **[user_database1]**:

```
                       prefix_table                   
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|     id     | name    | comment    | age | person_id |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 1111       | namenew | old text 1 | 99  | 001       |
+------------+---------+------------+-----+-----------+
| 4444       | name4   | old text 4 | 04  | 004       |
+------------+---------+------------+-----+-----------+
| 5555       | name5   | text 1     | 05  | 005       |
+------------+---------+------------+-----+-----------+
| 6666       | name6   | text 2     | 06  | 006       |
+------------+---------+------------+-----+-----------+
```

So it basically has to check if the table [prefix_table] matches in both databases then overwrite the data in the [comment] column. Note that if other column data changes, it should leave it as is, only the [comment] should be updated.

---

**In Summary** (both databases are on same server in one phpMyAdmin account)

FROM: [user_database0].[prefix_table].[content]

TO: [user_database1].[prefix_table].[content]

IF: [id] column matches in both tables.

---

Here is a **working version** from the recommendations below:

```
UPDATE
  [new_db_name].[table_name]
INNER JOIN 
  [old_db_name].[table_name]
ON 
  [new_db_name].[table_name].[column name] = [old_db_name].[table_name].[column name]
SET 
  [new_db_name].[table_name].[matching column name] = [new_db_name].[table_name].[matching column name]
```

Comment: What do you mean by merge - only update column `comments` where ther is a match between both tables or also insert missing rows from the backup?

Comment: Sorry, my terminology may be wrong here but I'm just trying to replace the "comments" column data from old database if id match occurs.No to inserting new rows.  Currently testing solution below to see if that works.

Comment: Then the aswer bellow is ok for you

Comment: Unfortunately the answer below did not work for me... due to the possibility of different syntax in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: You tagged the question also with `mysql` but the syntax you have shown is SQL Server specific. What exactly are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Actually it's the other way round: the "working version" in the question is MySQL, so `sql-server` is (was) the redundant tag (as well as the meaningless `database`).

Comment: @AndriyM: the but the `update` statement is clearly for SQL Server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: If you mean the UPDATE statement in the accepted answer, then yes, absolutely, it's for SQL Server (`UPDATE ... SET ... FROM ... JOIN...`). The UPDATE statement in the question, however, uses MySQL syntax (`UPDATE ... JOIN ... SET ...`).

Comment: @AndriyM: the "quoted" identifier `[table_name]` is (non-standard) SQL Server specific.

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin so pretty sure that would be only for MySQL. @AndriyM Ahhh, that makes sense why the original answer did not work without removing the (FROM) and switching order of (SET and JOIN) . Good to know that both versions are working, just different syntax. Learned something new:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work. Here it is updating the new comment with the old comment for any matching IDs in both.

Edit: This should point you in the correct direction. I had your schema before, I misunderstood what you wrote - my bad.

```
UPDATE [new_table_name] SET comment = [old_table_name].onecomment
  FROM [new_table_name]
  INNER JOIN [old_table_name] ON [new_table_name].aboutme_id = [old_table_name].aboutme_id
```

*Note: the above syntax is SQL Server because the question was at first erroneously tagged [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server).*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still having some trouble trying to test it though and keep getting thew following error: (http://screencast.com/t/yj2NTIhwbeL). I tried replacing everything with relevant and different databases but the error was the same.  Also, I see no mention of the actual table name that's inside both databases wich is "tb_aboutme", should that not be part of the query?

Comment: Does dbold stand for database owner, as in database user? What is "dbnew" in your example?

Comment: Sorry, a little more confusion came in..  by [new_table_name] do you mean [new_database_name]? I am trying to to update a field from  another table that's in in another database. I will see if it works if I just add on the database name in front of each time you mentioned the table name and see if that works: [new_database_name].[new_table_name]

Comment: I updated the bottom of my original posts with some more generic data of what is needed. In my real example only the database name is different and tables and fields are exactly the same. So after testing by chnaging around the order of some commands (UPDATE [user_database1].[prefix_table]
 JOIN [user_database1].[prefix_table]
 ON [user_database1].[prefix_table].[id] = [user_database1].[prefix_table].[id]
 SET [content] = [user_database1].[prefix_table].[content];)  --- It said that Column 'comment' in field list is ambiguous which I read may require using some kind of aliases for the fields?

Comment: If you receive such error this means that you must add alias. From my point of view the above exmaple is ok. If you want you can add `[new_table_name]` before `comment` in the `SET`. It will looks like `[new_table_name] SET [new_table_name].comment`. I think that it is not necessary, because during the update you can update only one table. In `T-SQL` fully qualified name (FQN) is `[db name].[schema owner].[table name].[column name]`. Try that, ause I see that you did not add that in your final exmaple. If you are not sure which is the onwer you can ommit it like `[db name]..[table name]`.

Comment: Thanks, adding the FQN worked fine with the example I added (with FROM part removed completely from query)

Comment: If you are going after another DB or schema then here would be the full syntax:

UPDATE [DB].[Schema].[new_table_name] SET comment = [DB].[Schema].[old_table_name].onecomment
  FROM [DB].[Schema].[new_table_name]
  INNER JOIN [DB].[Schema].[old_table_name] ON [DB].[Schema].[new_table_name].aboutme_id = [DB].[Schema].[old_table_name].aboutme_id